# Question's author changes tags to irrelevant after edit

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently stumbled upon this question: [B+ Tree order of 1 & 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359511/b-tree-order-of-1-2?noredirect=1#comment108547748_61359511) and removed all the tags regarding programming languages since it is general algorithmic question. But the author added more irrelevant tags regarding programming language. In general, what should I do if question's author adds tags to extend the visibility of the question? Flag for moderation? Vote to close?

Comment: Roll back, leave a comment. Preferably in the inverse order, because typing a comment is slower than rolling back. If they roll back again after that (or re-add tags or whatever), mod flag. The comment is enough to warn them that they shouldn't, which means further action falls outside the scope of what can be defended by "I wasn't aware"